# Added shapefile is not visible when I zoom

Tags: qgis, zoom

The CRS on all three layers are the same. I have tried deleting the PRJ file and reloading. I have also tried Vector> geometry tools> check validity with no errors.

[image: ![this the shape file, the purple dots are my data there are 2 other files lines and text]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4TcK.png)

[image: so when I zoom in the dots disappear]

Comment: I don't think you missed it but its worth a shot: Is "scale dependent visibility" checked in the general tab of the properties? Some sources like OpenStreetMap have this option checked by default.

Comment: Could you annotate your graphics to show us what you are talking about? Is it the blue blobs on the first plot? Are they hidden under the linework? Can you supply a shapefile that has this problem?

Comment: none of the layers have "scale dependent visibility" checked

Comment: yes the blue blobs in the railway is the layer I have added

Comment: the second pic is when I have zoomed in showing that my new shape file disappears...I thought I had labelled these.

Comment: not sure how to share the shapefiles...I can as I have got very small files where this problem is occurring

Comment: Perhaps through a file hosting site like www.filedropper.com or http://www.wikisend.com, and publishing the link in the comment. But after some time the link will get invalid.

Comment: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/sh/aiaiuzm5w3iattj/AADtJeLy1Q1EmS4lJ8QWnkaKa?dl=0

Comment: Please see the shapefiles in the drop box above the Pirbright line and  the textPir are the background the chambers is the shapefile with my data in which is disappearing

Answer (score 4):

According to the metadata for your point layer, there seems to be a problem with the extent:

> **Extents**
>
> *In layer spatial reference system units*
>
> unknown extent

I believe this is the cause of your points disappearing.

To rectify this, re-save the layer using the **Save As...** option and select the relevant CRS (which I assume is `EPSG:27700`, the same as the other 2 layers). You should now be able to zoom into the points:

[image: New point layer]

Comment: Export to vector file failed.
Error: creation of layer failed (OGR error:Failed to open Shapefile `B_Chambers.shp'.
)  Thanks Joesph...when I save as I get this error message and it doesn't create a new file...

Comment: @SallyO'Hara - Where are you saving the shapefile? Sometimes it fails because you need permission to write to a specific directory.

Comment: Hi Joseph you are right!! I was saving it in a stupid place now it is ok and it is fixed.  Thanks very much for that.  I'm not sure how you could tell from the meta data though - when I looked from the properties there was nothing listed

Comment: @SallyO'Hara - Awesome, glad you got it fixed! And most welcome! When you scroll down the properties, the 2nd last section details the extent of the layer which mentioned it was unknown for your "Chambers" point layer =)

Comment: ok this is right - thanks again for your help.  Sally

Comment: @SallyO'Hara please consider to mark the answer as accepted: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers